# VUEJS 2 Putting 2 props in one line

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

how do you input 2 props in one line in VUEJS?
Im using vuejs 2 and element UI.

```
<el-table-column prop="`(creator_name + creator_username)`" label="Founder"></el-table-column>
```

The output should be

test(09123567)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Vue, you can passing the variable as props with colon as prefix

in your case:

`` <el-table-column :prop="`${creator_name} ${creator_username})`" label="Founder"></el-table-column> ``

Answer (score 1):

in Vue you have to put `:` before a property to dynamically assign value to it. in your case it should be

```
<el-table-column :prop="creator_name + creator_username" label="Founder"></el-table-column>
```